# Batch database results before processing next query

Tags: c#, system.reactive

The code executes before the last result set has been processed:

```
var rxQueryTimeOut = pollingPeriodInSeconds + dbQueryTimeoutInSeconds;
var scheduler = new EventLoopScheduler(ts => new Thread(ts) {Name = "DatabasePoller"});
query = Observable.Interval(rxQueryTimeOut, scheduler).ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)
    .Select(_ => dbQuery.LoadItemsFromDB(LastFetchedRecord)).Do((x) => DoSomething(x, itemsMgr))
    .Retry() //Loop on errors
    .Repeat(); //Loop on success

query.Subscribe();

private void DoSomething(List<ItemDBData> theoDataDbs, IItemsMgr itemsMgr)
{
    foreach(var theoData in theoDataDbs)
    {

    }
}
```

Before `DoSomething` finishes executing, `Observable.Interval` fires again.

I tried:

```
private void DoSomething(List<ItemDBData> items, IItemsMgr itemsMgr)
{
    if(items.Count> 0)
        LastFetchedRecord = items[items.Count-1].TimeStamp;

    foreach(var itemData in items)
    {

    }
}
```

But I think each interval discards the last query request because I'm losing data.  How do  I solve this?

Comment: Looks like you want a polling instead of a push based solution. Why not use AsyncEnumerable then? If you want a solution where your subscribers can notify back to the source that they are finished processing you need to provide a callback then

Comment: @FelixKeil It is polling then notifying to subscribers. Will look at AsyncEnumerable

Comment: Sorry, Polling is wrong meaning in my previous comment. Please replace with "pull based". With Enumerable you request the next value (pull), which you can see as an implicit callback that you are finished processing. If you still need it as Observable common strategies for this issue are Buffer, Throttle extension methods.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to process the new rows in the database table every X seconds?

It will lose data when it cannot process all the rows in one query before the timer runs out.

Without more detail it's difficult to see the problem.

Consider looking how many blocking operations are done while processing the rows returned by the database query.  A common problem is to get lots of rows back and then foreach loop on them and do one or more database round trips for each row of data.

Comment: Well yes, I'm doing a database fetch every interval. But I want to process all the items from the fetch before the next interval. I thought Observable.Interval was meant to wait by default. But it seems once Subscribe gets fired it proceeds. Your 'answer' should be a comment btw